# Place picker in android close immediately after opening

Tags: android

Place picker in android close immediately after opening. I have enabled place api distance api map sdk in Google api console. I have added api key in manifest file with meta data

Answer (score 0):

Please share your logs, because it has many reasons to close. Either place api not enabled or api key is not setted correctlt

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the **API-key** that you are using in [Google-API's Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials), try to edit your API-Key configs as:

> 1) Application restrictions -> **NONE**
>
> 2) API restrictions -> **'Don't restrict key'**

Note: Changes may take about 10 minutes to reflect on the api-key, so edit and wait.

I hope my answer helps you.